# How to force Visual Studio to put multiple cases for one outcome in a switch on the same line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, switch-statement

This is how I want my C# code to look:

```
switch (foo)
            {
                case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3:
                    //Do something
                    break;
                case 4: case 5: case 6:
                    //Do something else
                    break;
        }
```

This is how Visual Studio formats it:

```
switch (foo)
            {
                case 0: 
                case 1: 
                case 2: 
                case 3:
                    //Do something
                    break;
                case 4: 
                case 5: 
                case 6:
                    //Do something else
                    break;
        }
```

The extra lines are totally unnecessary and a waste of space. How do I get Visual Studio to stop changing how I format my switch statements? I looked through the settings and found nothing.

Comment: Your method leads to code that is hard to read and understand. The compiler doesn't care about the *wasted space*, and neither should you.

Comment: It seems like Visual Studio currently doesn't have that functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use  C# 9.0 or higher, you can make use of the [`or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) operator:

```
switch (foo)
{
    case 0 or 1 or 2 or 3:
         //Do something
         break;
    case 4 or 5 or 6:
         //Do something else
         break;
}
```